# Mertens' function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

I am tasked with applying the Wiener-Ikehara Theorem to achieve a bound of little o(x) on Mertens' function $\sum_{n=1}^x \mu (n)$. My problem is the Wiener-Ikehara Theorem applies to Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n) n^{-s}$ only when $a(n)$ is non-negative but clearly $\mu(n)$ can be negative although its absolute value is bounded by $1$. I also know this Dirichlet series can b e extended to a meromorphic function in the region $\mathbf{R}(s) \geq1$ having only a simple pole at s=1 with residue $R\geq0$ which gives $\sum_{n=1}^x a(n) =Rx+ o(x)$ as x goes to $\infty$. But I am unsure as to how I should work around the fact that my a(n) will not always be non negative.

Comment: Perhaps the name "Wiener-Ikehara Theorem" is actually referring to the proof of the zero-free region of the zeta function, or something of that nature. The statement that $\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) = o(x)$ is equivalent to the prime number theorem. Sometimes proofs of the final steps of the prime number theorem are attributed to Wiener-Ikehara.

Answer (score 2):

The Möbius function isn't non-negative, but it is bounded. Hence we obtain a non-negative sequence by adding a suitable constant to it. With $a(n) = 1 + \mu(n)$, we have

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a(n)}{n^s} = \zeta(s) + \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$$

for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$. Since $a(n) \geqslant 0$ and $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on the line $\operatorname{Re} s = 1$, the assumptions of the Wiener-Ikehara theorem are satisfied, whence

$$\sum_{n \leqslant x} a(n) \sim x.$$

Consequently

$$\frac{M(x)}{x} = \frac{\sum_{n\leqslant x} a(n) - \lfloor x\rfloor}{x} \xrightarrow{x\to +\infty} 1 - 1 = 0.$$